# Get DIV's height with overflow-y:scroll and updated content

Tags: jquery, html, height, scrolltop

I have a regular empty DIV with overflow-y:scroll; I update that div with content via something like $(elem).html(new_content);

Now this is where I get lost. I need to get the height of the entire DIV with new content. Normally it'd be done through ScrollTop setting but the problem is that the $(elem)[0].scrollHeight is zero!!

How do I solve this issue?

UPDATE: I solved the issue. Turns out that my call was in the callback function of the JQuery UI effect. The call back function was supposed to bring the DIV to be visible. Somehow even though it's a callback function the DIV was still not visible. So, I had to setTimeout to like 10 mS and then it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<button>Button</button>
```

JS:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  //BEFORE HTML INSERTED, DIV IS EMPTY
  var height = $("div").scrollTop($("div"))[0].scrollHeight;
  console.log(height); //Outputs 1 (the starting div height)
  alert(height);

  //Add more <p>TEST4</p> and see that height SCROLLHEIGHT does indeed grow/update.
  $("div").html("<p>TEST</p><p>TEST2</p><p>TEST3</p>");
  $("div").height(50); // DIV starts at 1PX, and we set to 50PX so that we can see contents.

  //AFTER HTML INSERTED
  height = $("div").scrollTop($("div"))[0].scrollHeight;
  console.log(height); //Outputs 124 (the scroll height, notice the actual div height is 50)
  alert(height);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/dHZJc/)

Comment: No, that just gives me the height of the VISIBLE portion of the DIV. But I want the entire height of ALL of the content.

Comment: That's the answer that I originally posted as a non-working code. The scrollHeight returns zero because that's what the original height of the content was until it got updated.

Comment: Check the fiddle, it's working... updated answer. Are you sure you're calling $("div").scrollTop($("div"))[0].scrollHeight; AFTER your html content has been added? That might be the reason it still outputs 0..

Answer (score 0):

use .height() and check every time you update the div

```
function newContent(){

    $('#test').html(new_content);
    var h = $('#test').height();
    console.log('new height is ' + h);

}
```

here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F5K6H/